# Boot Camp: "no bootable device found" when booting from DVD

Tags: bootcamp, dvd

My Mac mini couldn't boot from a Windows 8 DVD after running Boot Camp Assistant. The DVD was bootable and I verified with Parallels that it was indeed so.

Mac mini server 2012, 2x1 TB, Apple DVD drive connected to Thunderbolt display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when I connected the DVD drive directly to the Mac mini it could boot with no problems.

Apparently Thunderbolt cannot be used for booting, at least not for non-network booting.

Note that I also tried to let Boot Camp Assistant create a bootable USB stick which utterly failed and took hours to do so. Safest bet appears to be a bootable DVD and a DVD drive connected directly to the Mac.